# Make Python 3.6.6 run with python3 and not python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed python 3.6.6 on my server as python 3.7 was giving me too many issues.  Unfortunately instead of showing up as python3 executable it is only python.  here is the results of `dir`:

```
aclocal.m4     config.sub    Include          Mac              Modules  Programs        Python            setup.py
build          configure     install-sh       Makefile         Objects  pybuilddir.txt  python-config     Tools
config.guess   configure.ac  Lib              Makefile.pre     Parser   pyconfig.h      python-config.py
config.log     Doc           libpython3.6m.a  Makefile.pre.in  PC       pyconfig.h.in   python-gdb.py
config.status  Grammar       LICENSE          Misc             PCbuild  python          README.rst
```

I have edited the env path to go to this directory

```
[root@server]# echo $PATH
/usr/src/Python-3.6.6/python:$PATH
```

and even

```
/usr/src/Python-3.6.6/
```

but obviously that wouldn't work because the python3 command doesn't even exist in the directory.  I tried renaming python to python3 so it would run it.  Currently the server came with python 2.6.6 and I don't want to disturb that version as I only need this for one piece of software.  Though I need to use pip3 and if the system can't find python3 then pip3 command is also not found.  Would it have to do with this install process?:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
make altinstall
```

I wasn't sure if the `make altinstall` was screwing with it but.

Comment: there must be `make` command before `make altinstall`. If this doesn't work, you should dump the output of these commands into some external resource (like pastebin.com) and attach it there, and we will try to help you

Comment: Here is the config command logs: [https://pastebin.com/QYq1ekpz](https://pastebin.com/QYq1ekpz) I will get the rest hold on, it's currently running `./python -m test.regrtest --pgo || true`

Comment: Here is the `make` command logs: [https://pastebin.com/kQtfPgWz](https://pastebin.com/kQtfPgWz)

Comment: `make altinstall` logs part 1: [https://pastebin.com/80JhHVs2](https://pastebin.com/80JhHVs2)
`make altinstall` logs part 2: [https://pastebin.com/s12Facgk](https://pastebin.com/s12Facgk)

Comment: I'd expect the executable you're looking for to be in `/usr/local/bin` after you install it. Do you see it there? It might be named more specifically than you want (e.g. `python3.6`, not just `python3`). You can probably fix that with a symlink. In any case, your `PATH` should name a folder, not a specific file.

Comment: Good god man that solved all my problems xD  Even from python 3.7 gezus.. Such a simple thing...  Sorry for my stupidity, i'm learning

Answer (score 0):

`python -3 -m ....`

Or

`py -3 -m ....`

Anything wrong these?

[EDIT]

Further to your comment, it sounds like it could be one of the following:

1. The file you're trying to use is not in the PATH variable. 
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path
2. Python 3.6 is not in its default position after installation or has been renamed after installation.

Where possible, and practicable, if you're unsure, then ALWAYS install with the relevant installation tool, e.g. `apt-get`. As far as I'm aware, this will automatically add the directory for Python to the `$PATH` variable. You can also type that variable into the CLI if you really want to manually check it is 100% in the PATH.

Comment: the python -3 will launch python if I am in the Python-3.6.6 directory but nowhere else.  Anywhere else it starts python 2.6.6.  py is not recognized as a command anywhere